# Random integer from an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm just practicing my skills using multiple classes and using System.out.println.

I'm trying to make a program in which you have a 'conversation' with the computer. What I'd like to try and do is instead of the computer having the same age every time the console is run, use an array to list a load of random ages, which will then be randomly selected. In my computer class I've got:

```
    static int [] compAge = {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};
```

and in my main conversation class, I've got:

```
int Uage = input.nextInt(); // (Uage is user age)
System.out.println("That's cool! You're " +Uage+ ". I'm " + (Computers age here) + " myself. Where do you live?");
```

I've read around a bit and found code such as

```
compAge[new Random().nextInt(compAge.length)]
```

But in all honestly my knowledge of arrays and using the random function (I have imported it) is very limited and I'm not really sure where to go.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: What is your question and what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.Random instead:

```
int age = ((int)Math.random()*13)+19;
```

It will give you a number between 0 and 12 and add 19 to it!
The nice thing is that you have to change only the values here to change the range of age and not add values to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
compAge[new Random().nextInt(compAge.length() )]
```

The `new Random().nextInt()` generates a random positive number. If you use the `compAge.length()`, you set the max value (exclusively, so this will not be picked ever).

That way, you get a random age everytime you start your program.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to generate a random number.  The general usage of Math.random is:

```
// generates a floating point random number greater than 0 
// and less  than largestPossibleNumber
float randomNumber = Math.random() * largestPossibleNumber;

// generates an integer random number between greater than 0 
// and less than largestPossibleNumber
int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * largestPossibleNumber);

// generates an integer random number greater than 1 
// and less than or equal to largestPossibleNumber
int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * largestPossibleNumber) + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select ramdomly from array use this:

```
     static int [] compAge = {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};
```

With this you have random index of array:

```
      int age = new Random().nextInt(compAge.length);
```

And to display to value like this:

```
    System.out.println("Random value of array compAge  : " + compAge[age]);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class MainConversation {

     public static void main (String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
       int [] compAge = {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}; 
      System.out.println("Enter a random number between 0 and  "+ (compAge.length-1));
     int numb;
    while(input.hasNextInt() && (numb = input.nextInt()) < compAge.length){
 // int age = new Random().nextInt(compAge.length);
      System.out.println("Random value of array compAge : " + compAge[numb]); 
      }
    } 
   }
```

Comment: Hi there. I didn't down vote you honestly, I never do that for people trying to help me out.
In my Computer class, do I need to create a constructor, or because the int [] compAge is static, I can leave this? Because in my mainConversation it's saying that + compAge[age]) is undefined? Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: Try to post your class @CalumMullen

Comment: Sure thing. So my computer class is:
import java.util.Random;     
public class Computer {     
static int [] compAge = {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};      
static int compAge = new Random().nextInt(compAge.length);
 }

Comment: And then in my MainConversation class I've got:     

import java.util.Scanner;      
public class MainConversation {     
public static void main (String[] args) {      
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);      
System.out.println("Random value of array compAge : " + compAge[age]); }     
}

Comment: Sorry it's like that, I tried to separate each line but I've not used this website much, not sure if you can enter the code like in the question?